# How to send data to component in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

How do I send data to a component in Vue.js? I got a response from the server on the button click event, and now I want to send this response to the component and display on `list` using `v-for`.

Here is my code:

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        Item: []
    },
    mutations: {
        getItems: function (state) {

        }

    },
    actions: {
        fetchData:function (context) {
           Vue.http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
             alert('dd')
}, function(error){
    console.log(error.statusText);
});

        }
    }
})

var httprequest = Vue.extend({
    "template": '#http_template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            items: store.state.Item
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
          store.dispatch('fetchData')
        },

    }
})

Vue.component('httprequest', httprequest);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#App',
    data: {},


});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to share data between components in VUE js (while creating list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015442/how-to-share-data-between-components-in-vue-js-while-creating-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost done everything correct. Only thing you are missing is after getting data, you are not assigning it to `state.Item`. Please check the below code:

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      Item: []
    },
    mutations: {
      getItems: function(state, items) {
        items.forEach(function(item) {
          state.Item.push(item)
        })
      }
    },
    actions: {
      fetchData: function(context) {
        Vue.http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
          context.commit('getItems', response.data)
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error.statusText);
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

working example can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tJRruqwMS8ZZEpWRmArp?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

In general vue follows the principle that data goes the DOM tree down via properties and up via events. See for example https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Composing-with-Components.

Thus to get data into your component define a property `myProp` inside your component and when using your component bind it via `v-bind:myProp="myData"`.

To get data back from your component use `this.$emit('myUpdateEvent', myUpdatedData)` and listen to the event by using `v-on:myUpdateEvent="myUpdateHandler"`.

Comment: please remove this anwser .I am using vuex not emit

Comment: please check my plunker.I am not using emit or broadcast

Comment: The principles I am pointing out are very much relevant for your use case: if you have a generic list component you would not want to bind Vuex data directly inside it, but instead bind it to the parent component and pass it to the list as property as explained.

Answer (score 1):

You don't send data to components. You set up reactive pipes and the data moves around when it needs to. In your case, with vuex, you want to register store.state.items on the data of your component.

You can use a prop if you want, but you still need to do the registration in the parent's data. If your component is a singleton, intended for this page only, you're better registering what you need directly in the data of the component.