# Vue js sharing data between child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to send data from one component to another one without any success. I have one parent component *App.vue* and two child components *Base.vue* and *Ingredients.vue*. Mainly I' would like to send dynamic *{{selectedBase.price}}* (which is updated every time you select/deselect the option) from Base component to Ingredients component and being rendered on Ingredients component dynamically.

I imported and defined *my-base* and *my-ingredients* components on the main.js file

```
//App.vue

<v-app light>
    <main>
        <v-container fluid>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <my-base ></my-base>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3 class="text-xs-center">
                <my-ingredients></my-ingredients>
            </v-flex>
        </v-container>
    </main>
</v-app>


//Ingredients.vue

  <v-layout row v-for="ingredient in ingredients" :key="ingredient.id">
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex xs6 offset-xs5>
                <v-checkbox class="text-xs-right" name="checkbox" color="light-blue lighten-2" v-bind:label="`${ingredient.name}`" v-model="ingredient.checked" light></v-checkbox>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex xs6 offset-xs5>
                <v-subheader>{{ingredient.price}} €</v-subheader>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-layout>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-layout row wrap class="mb-3">
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex xs6 offset-xs3>
                <h3 class="headline mb-0">Total price:</h3>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex xs6 offset-xs4>
                <v-subheader> {{total}}  €</v-subheader>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-layout>

   <script>


export default {


    data: () => ({

        checked1: '',
        showCart: false,
        ingredients: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "Mozzarella",
            price: 2,
            checked: '',
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "Cheddar",
            price: 2.0,
            checked: '',
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "Bacon",
            price: 2.25,
            checked: '',
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "Mushrooms",
            price: 1.6,
            checked: '',
        }, {
            id: 5,
            name: "Pepperoni",
            price: 2.5,
            checked: '',
        }, {
            id: 6,
            name: "Sucuk",
            price: 2.75,
            checked: '',
        }],


    }),

    computed: {

        total: function() {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.ingredients.length; i++) {
                if (this.ingredients[i].checked) {
                    total += this.ingredients[i].price;
                }

            }
            return total;
        }
    }

}

</script>

//Base.vue

<v-layout row wrap primary-title v-for="base in bases" :key="base.id">
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex xs6 offset-xs3>
                <v-avatar size="80px" class="grey lighten-1">
                    <img :src="base.href" :class="{selected: selectedBase.id == base.id}" @click="selectedBase = base" alt="avatar">
                </v-avatar>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex xs6 offset-xs4>
                <v-subheader>{{base.name}} {{base.price}}€ {{selectedBase.price}}</v-subheader>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-layout>
</v-card>

</template>

<script>


export default {

    data() {

            return {
                selectedBase: {},
                bases: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Margarita",
                    price: 4,
                    href: "../../static/margarita.jpg"
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Salami",
                    price: 6,
                    href: "../../static/salami.jpg"
                }]
            }
        },

        computed: {

            totalBase() {
                var totalBase = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.bases.length; i++) {
                    if (this.bases[i].selected) {
                        totalBase += this.bases[i].price;
                    }
                }
                return totalBase;
            },
        methods: {
        getSelectedBase() {
                return this.selectedBase;
            }
    }
        }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share data between non parent-child components in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925841/how-can-i-share-data-between-non-parent-child-components-in-vue)

Comment: I see @thanksd , but i would like to know how to do it with Props or Events. thanks

Comment: Use prose with `v-bind` , the childs react on every change. Please just read the docu, this questions pops up every hour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to share data between components in VUE js (while creating list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015442/how-to-share-data-between-components-in-vue-js-while-creating-list)

Comment: You have to use Mixins for such cases if you want to share data between sibling components.